# npm install less throws error from ruby

Tags: node.js, rubygems, less, npm

I am trying to use the less, following their [getting started guide](http://lesscss.org/#getting-started)

I successfully ran `sudo npm install -g less` that ended with:

```
/usr/bin/lessc -> /usr/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
less@1.7.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/less
├── mime@1.2.11
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── source-map@0.1.33 (amdefine@0.1.0)
```

but when I try using lessc I get an error from Ruby:

```
$ lessc 
/home/jasonshark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'less' (>= 0) among 153 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/jasonshark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /home/jasonshark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /home/jasonshark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/lessc:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/jasonshark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/jasonshark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

What's this conflict and how do I fix it?

My `$PATH` variable is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/jasonshark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/jasonshark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/jasonshark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/jasonshark/.rvm/bin:/home/jasonshark/.rvm/bin:/home/jasonshark/Code/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/tools:/home/jasonshark/Code/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/jasonshark/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of your PATH variable?

Comment: how do I do that? typing `$PATH` into shell gives me `zsh: no such file or directory: /home/jasonshark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/jasonshark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/jasonshark/.rvm/ru...`

Comment: Well you pasted part of it. Try `echo $PATH` and put it into your question. (and comment here when you're done so I can look)

Comment: good ol `echo`. $PATH added

Comment: @connorLeech Could you fix this issue? I'm having the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ruby gem `less` is in conflict with the npm module `lessc`.  both the gem and the npm module contain an executable `lessc`.  Since RVM is appending the Ruby bin directories to the front of your path, you are running the Ruby `lessc` command when you are intending to run the npm `lessc` command.

To fix, run `/usr/bin/lessc`.  This is more explicit and will avoid invoking the Ruby `lessc`.